# How to obtain the offset by (x,y) in TextView when text is SpannableString

Tags: android, kotlin

I use TextView.layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x) to obtain the offset by x, but it returns a wrong answer when the text is SpannableString, it seems span will be treated as a character when invoke this method, so I can only obtain the offset of the span, not the character offset in the span

```
val layout = textView.layout ?: return -1
var line = layout.getLineForVertical(y)
var offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x.toFloat())
```

For example, the text is "i was fine", fine is a span, i can't obtain the offset of 'n'

Comment: What kind of span are you using that doesn't work?

Comment: ReplaceMentSpan

Comment: A _ReplacementSpan_ makes sense. You must be supplying your own _draw()_ method since it is a _ReplacementSpan_. The layout doesn't have any knowledge about what you draw in your own method. If you need a placement of text within the _ReplacementSpan_, you will need another way to do it other than ask the layout.

Comment: You may want to consider using a different type of span, if possible. This is a problem with _ReplacementSpan_ and not _SpannableStrings_.

Comment: OK,thanks. I used ForegroundColorSpan to solved this problem